# Decomposing a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $K=[a_1,b_1]\times\dots \times [a_d,b_d]$ be a closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and suppose that $K\subset\cup_{i=1}^n R_i$, where each $R_i$ is an open rectangle. In his measure theory book Cohn writes:

$K$ can be decomposed into a finite collection $\{K_j\}$ of rectangles that
overlap only on their boundaries and are such that for each $j$ the interior of $K_j$ is
included in some $R_i$.

If $\overline{R}_i$ denote the closure of $R_i$, then $K\cap\overline{R}_i$ is a closed rectangle. For each $1\leq m \leq d$, let $P_m$ denotes all the left and right $m$th coordinates appearing among the $K\cap\overline{R}_i$ $ (1\leq i\leq n)$. Then $P_m\subset [a_m,b_m]$, and if we order the elements of $P_m$ from left to right we obtain a partition of $[a_m,b_m]$ into a finite collection if closed intervals that overlap only at the boundary. Let $\{K_j\}$ denote the finite collection of all closed rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^d$ which are formed by taking $d$-products of those closed intervals (by choosing one closed interval in the partition of $[a_m,b_m]$ for each $m$). These rectangles intersect only at their boundaries and

$$K=\cup K_j$$

Indeed if $x\in K$, then $x_m \in [a_m,b_m]$ for each $m$, and so $x\in K_j$ for some $j$. Conversely if $x\in K_j$ for some $j$, then $x_m \in [a_m,b_m]$ for each $m$ and so $x\in K$.

Am stuck at proving that the interior of each $K_j$ is included in some $R_i$. It would suffice to show that $K_j\subset K\cap\overline{R}_i$ for some $i$. But I don't see how to show it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $\sup$ norm for convenience.

For $k \in K$, let $\delta(k) = \sup \{ r | B(k,r) \subset R_i \text{ for some } i\}$. Since the $R_i$ are open we see that $\delta(k) > 0$ for all $k$.

Let $\delta= \inf_{k \in K} \delta(k)$, it is straightforward to show that $\delta>0$ and for any $k$ there is some $R_i$ such that $B(k,\delta) \subset R_i$.

Let $l_i = b_i-a_i$ and take the rectangles $$\Delta_{n,k_1,...,k_d} = [a_1+{k_1 \over n} l_1, a_1+{k_1+1 \over n} l_1] \times \cdots \times [a_d+{k_d \over n} l_d, a_d+{k_d+1 \over n} l_d] $$
with  ${1 \over n} < \delta$.
Note that for each $n$ we have  $K = \cup_{k_i=0,...,n-1} \Delta_{n,k_1,...,k_d}$.

Since the center of each rectangle lies in some $R_i$, we see that each rectangle lies in some $R_i$.

**Addendum**:

To see why $\delta>0$: Suppose $\delta=0$ then there is some sequence $k_i$ such that $\delta(k_i) \to 0$. Without loss of generality we can assume $k_k \to k$. We know that $\delta(k) >0$ and hence for $k_i$
sufficiently close to $k$ we have $\delta(k_i) \ge {1 \over 2} \delta(k)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't see the relationship of those rectangles with the $K_j$. Could you expand on that?

Comment: They form a partition of $K$ by dividing up the sides of $K$.

Comment: I see so this is a different partition then mine. When you write $1/n<\delta$ do you you mean $n$ large enough so that that the distance of any point in a rectangle from the center is less than $\delta$? I believe the exact value must be such that $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^d (\frac{l_i}{2n})^2}<\delta$

Comment: I mean literatlly what I wrote. Since I am using the $\sup$ distance ($\max$ norm?) it will work. Figuring an exact number has no real value here.

Comment: Ok I see so all your balls $B(k,r)$ are taken with respect to the max norm. And at the end when you write "the center of each rectangle lies in some $R_i$", do you mean in $K$? Your previous analysis shows that for any $k\in K$ we have $B(k,\delta) \subset R_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: No, I mean the centre of each $\Delta_{n,k_1,...,k_d}$ lies in some $R_i$ and so the entire $\Delta_{n,k_1,...,k_d}$ is contained in $R_i$.

Comment: I have been studying your answer carefully for some time, but I can't see we why $\delta>0$. I believe I was able to show it in the case $d=1$, but I don't see how to generalize. Do have any hints?

Comment: @Alphie I added an elaboration.

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed you can extract a convergent subsequence $k_k \to k \in K$ since $K$ is compact. What about the claim that $B(k,\delta) \subset R_i$ for some $i$ for any $k$? If not then $\delta=\delta(k)$ for some $k$, but I don't see where to find a contradiction.

Comment: I guess I could just take $\delta/2$, but I how to show it for $\delta$?

Comment: I don't follow your question. If $\delta(k') >0$ then for $x$ sufficiently near $k'$ you must have $\delta(x) \ge {1 \over 2} \delta(k')$.

Comment: Yes but I was not talking about the addendum. I was talking about the other claim above that for any $k$ there is some $R_i$ such that $B(k,\delta) \subset R_i$.

Comment: Well, $K$ is contained in the union and each $R_i$ is open??? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: For the specific $\delta:= \inf_{k \in K} \delta(k)$, why is it true that for any $k\in K$ we have $B(k,\delta) \subset R_i$ for some $i$? Don't we need to take $\delta/2$?

Comment: Well, you  can do it any way that you are comfortable with, but $\delta \le \delta(k)$ for all $k$. So you just need to show that for eack $k$ there is some $i$ such that $B(k,\delta(k)) \subset R_i$. But if you would rather take ${\delta \over 2}$ and not fuss with that part that will work too.

Comment: Exactly, but how to show this? In other words how to show that the $\sup$ is attained at $\delta(k)$? Just to  complete.

Comment: Well, you need to do some work here. For any $n$ you can find some $i_n$ such that $B(k,\delta(k)-{1 \over n}) \subset R_{i_n}$. At least one of the $i_n$'s will occur infinitely often. That means that $B(k,\delta(k)-{1 \over n}) \subset R_{i'}$ infinitely often for a specific $i'$ and from that you can see that $B(k,\delta(k)) \subset R_{i'}$.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. One last thing: The center $c$ of each rectangle $\Delta_{n,k_1,...,k_d} $ lies in $K$  and the previous analysis shows that $B(c,\delta) \subset R_i$ for some $i$, and since each rectangle fits in its respective $B(c,\delta)$ we see that each lies in $R_i$ for some $i$.  But why do you emphasize the fact that each center $c$ lies in some $R_i$? It seems to me that the key is that the center of each rectangle lies in $K$.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say I emphasised it. You just need to show that $\Delta_{n,k_1,...,k_d}$ is completely contained in some $R_i$. You could pick any corner, edge, center, whatever works for you.

Comment: I mean, you should step back and look at the idea of the proof first. If you focus too much on details (which are important, of course) you will get lost. The big idea is that if you chop the big rectangle up into sufficiently small ones, then every little rectangle is completely contained in at least one of the $R_i$s. I'm not sure why the author even bothered with dealing with the interiors of the $K_j$, that is a distracting detail as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Yes your rectangles are (much) smaller than the ones I used in my question. But is my reasoning above with the centers in $K$ correct or am I making a mistake?

Comment: If you are referring to your second last comment, it doesn't really matter what point of the small rectangle you use. I just picked the middle for definiteness. If you pick any point in the small rectangles then there is some $R_i$ that contains the entire small rectangle.

Comment: If we pick any two points in a rectangle then their max norm distance is at most $\max\{l_1/n,\dots, l_d/n\}$. This is not necessarily  smaller than $\delta$ no?

Comment: But I get the idea. Thanks a lot for your patience I learned a lot.

Comment: You are correct, I should have something like ${1 \over n} \max_i(b_i-a_i) < \delta$.

Comment: I attempted to finish my solution below.  I would very appreciate if you could give me some feedback. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong?

Comment: The downvote is not from me. I really like your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I will finish the approach I proposed originaly. This approach might be closer to what Cohn had in mind.

Assume $K^\circ\neq \emptyset$ and $K\cap R_i \neq \emptyset$ for each $i$. Write
$K\cap \bar{R}_i=[a^i_1,b^i_1]\times\dots\times[a^i_d,b^i_d]$. Note that $K=\cup_{i=1}^n K\cap \bar{R}_i$. For each $j=1,\dots,d$, let

$$a_j=c_j^1<c^2_j<\dots<c_j^{m_j}=b_j$$

be the list of all distinct numbers among $a_j^i$ and $b_{j}^i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. Denote by $\mathcal{L}$ any $n$-tuple of the form $\mathcal{L}=(l_1,\dots,l_d)$ with $1\leq l_j\leq m_j$. Then denote

$$K^{\mathcal{L}}=[c_1^{l_1},c_1^{l_1+1}]\times\dots\times[c_d^{l_d},c_d^{l_d+1}]$$

Clearly $K=\cup\{K^{\mathcal{L}}\}$ and the $K^{\mathcal{L}}$ overlap only on their boundaries. Suppose $(K^{\mathcal{L}})^\circ \cap (K\cap \bar{R}_i) \neq \emptyset$ for some $\mathcal{L}$ and $i$. Then $c_j^{l_j}<x_j<c_j^{l_j+1}$ and $a^i_j\leq x_j\leq b^i_j$ for $1\leq j\leq d$. By the choice of the $c_j$'s we must have $a^i_j\leq c_j^{l_j}<x_j<c_j^{l_j+1}\leq b^i_j$. Thus $K^{\mathcal{L}}\subset K\cap \bar{R}_i\subset \bar{R}_i$ and hence $(K^{\mathcal{L}})^\circ\subset\bar{R}_i^\circ=R_i$. This shows that the interior of $K^{\mathcal{L}}$ is included in some $R_i$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a face $[a_{ir},b_{ir}]$? A face is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes sorry I mean a side of a rectangle. I edited my answer. Otherwise is the proof good?

Comment: I still don't follow. How is $C_{ir}$ defined?

Comment: @copper.hat It is the set of all endpoints determining the $r$th side of some rectangle $K\cap \bar{R}_j$ with $i\neq j$. For example, if  $[a_{jr},b_{jr}]$ is the $r$th side of $K\cap \bar{R}_j$ for some  $j\neq i$, then $a_{jr}$ and $b_{jr}$ both belong to this set

Comment: @copper.hat I added a clarification below the definition of $C_{ir}$.

Comment: I do not understand how you can order the points, these are points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @copper.hat No they are points in $\mathbb{R}$. The $r$th side of a rectangle is an interval $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}$ and its endpoints are elements of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Just to be clear if $R=[a_1,b_1]\times \dots \times [a_d,b_d]$ is a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$ then its $r$th side is the interval $[a_r,b_r]\subset\mathbb{R}$ with endpoints $a_r,b_r\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am getting a little lost in your notation and exactly what you are trying to do. $R$ is a collection of rectangles which are written as the union of some $K_j$ which are not defined. Each $K_j$ is a collection of rectangles, but on the next line their union equals $K$? Would it not be simpler to just take the union of the $i$ coordinates of each $K \cap R_i$ and partition $[a_i,b_i]$ accordingly and take the collection of rectangles formed by taking their products?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry I meant $\bigcup R=\cup_{j=1}^N K_j$. Basically am  discarding duplicates $R_{il}$. Yes this is exactly what I do, but by writting this way makes it easier to show that the interior of each resulting rectangle lies in some $R_i$. In other words I decompose each $K\cap \bar{R}_j$ and discard overlaps.

Comment: @copper.hat Were you able to go through my proof? I hope it is understandable.

Comment: There were no changes since I made my comments. I know what you are trying to do, but frankly there is only so much effort I can spend trying to unravel the details of the proof.

Comment: @copper.hat OK I understand

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a ¨bootstrap¨ approach, which should really be a comment, but is too long. I think if you do the proof in $\mathbb R^2$ by first drawing a picture, the idea will be much clearer and extends easily to $\mathbb R^n.$ We have $K=[a,b]\times [c,d]$ and $R_i=[a_i,b_i]\times [c_i,d_i].$ In the first place, because $K$ is compact and $(\cup_{i=1}^n R_i)^c$ is closed, and disjoint from $K,\ d(K,(\cup_{i=1}^n R_i)^c)=r>0,$ so you may assume that $\cup_{i=1}^n R_i$ is itself an open rectangle $R$ containing $K$ and concentric with $K$. Then, the picture tells the story. We will take $\overline R_i\cap \overline R_j$ for $1\le i,j\le n$ to produce the required rectangles. Explicitly: the $R_i$ are a collection of rectangles, at least two of which must overlap,  whose union is $R$. Now, project each rectangle $\overline R_i\cap K$ on the $x$ axis and then on the $y$ axis. We get a partition $P_x$ of $[a,b]$ and $P_y$ of $[c,d]$. Using these partitions, we get a collection of almost disjoint rectangles whose union is $K$,  with the desired property that the interior of each $[x_k,x_{k+1}]\times [y_l,y_{l+1}]$ lies strictly in some $R_i$: indeed, suppose $(z_1,w_1)$ and $(z_2,w_2)$ are both interior to $[x_k,x_{k+1}]\times [y_l,y_{l+1}]$ but lie in different $R_i.$ Without loss of generality $z_1<z_2.$ Then, by construction there is an  $x\in P_x$ and such that $z_1<x<z_2.$ This is a contradiction because by construction, there are no partition points between $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I will study it. I tried a similar approach in my answer above. Do you think its ok?

Comment: I will read it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much

Comment: Were you able to go through my proof? I hope it is understandable.

Comment: I am having a hard time following your proof. Idea: Do it $\mathbb R^2$ first.

Comment: OK I have rewritten my proof completely. It is very close to yours but am still having an issue with showing that the interior of each rectangle is contained in some $R_i$. In your proof it is the line "by construction there is an $x\in P_x$ and such that $z_1<x<z_2$". Why is this true?

Comment: I divided into four cases. Is this correct?

Comment: You are making this much harder than it is. Drawing a picture will tell you how to proceed. How about drawing, say 4 overlapping open rectangles whose union is a square with length 2  sides covering centrally the compact set $[-1/2,1/2]\times [-1/2,1/2].$ Then, take their closure, and project each on the x a y axis, resp. You will then see how  the partition points relate to the corners of the rectangles.

Comment: $(-1,1)\times(0,1)$ and $(-1,1)\times(-1,1/4)$ are open rectangles satisfying your requirements. We get a decomposition into three rectangles: $[-1/2,1/2]\times[-1/2,0]$,$[-1/2,1/2]\times[0,1/4]$ and $[-1/2,1/2]\times[1/4,1/2]$. Yet all interior points of $[-1/2,1/2]\times[0,1/4]$ belong to both open rectangles. This is what confuses me.

Comment: Whe you project the endpoints of the intervals on the x and y axis nd take products, you get "new" (sub)rectangles which satisfy the required conditions. All you are doing is forming from the overlaps almost disjoint subrectangles. Drawing the picture will help.

Comment: Lets look for example at the left drawing here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28GZM.jpg. We see that it is possible for a subrectangle to lie completely in two different $R_i$s. Hence the contradiction you derive at the end of your answer seems incorrect no?

Comment: Each partition point corresponds to a coordinate of a corner one of the subrectangles, There may be common coordinates but that does not matter. Simply take all intersections $R_i\cap R_j$ and you get almost disjoint rectangles. Now project these on the axes. I guess I am not following your argument. Sorry!